# Switch script with debug shell script vscode

Tags: shell, visual-studio-code, debugging, vscode-debugger

I am using Remote **VS Code Bash Debug** to debug shell scripts.
I want to know if there is a way to switch debugging from the main script to the script called by the main.

Example : main.sh script calls functions in fonctions_commun.sh script
I want to add breakpoints in the fonctions_commun.sh script and switch the debug to it
I put breakpoints in the fonctions_commun.sh script and it does not work
I use this configuration :
`{ "type": "bashdb", "request": "launch", "name": "Bash-Debug (select script from list of sh files)", "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}", "program": "${command:SelectScriptName}", "args": [], "showDebugOutput": true  }`

Answer (score 1):

The debug works from one script to another if we use the passage by (F5) but it does not work if we use (F10).